# iOS Detect Which Camera Was Used

Tags: ios, objective-c

I built an app that uses UIImagePickerController to let users take a picture with the device's camera. The user is able to use the Front Camera or the Rear Camera because I set showsCameraControls = YES.

How do I detect which camera was used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `UIImagePickerController`, you can find a property called `cameraDevice` which returns the camera used:

- `UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceFront`
- `UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceRear`

So, you can use a code like this one to know which camera is used:

```
if ([yourPickerController cameraDevice] == UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceFront) {
   // Front camera
} else {
   // Rear camera
}
```